# Problems in the group with a list of products for cart

Tags: html, angular, typescript

we are making an angular online shop and I have a question, since I am pretty new to it. We have a List of products, but for the cart i need one specific product of the list after pressed the button "add to cart" atm I am trying to figure this out in the product.component.ts
Which looks like this:

```
  @Input()
  productItem!: Product;//is from model but I think ptoducts(the list) is actually directly from the database
  products: any;
  private msg!: MessengerService;
  private cartService!: cartService;
  cartService!: cartService;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProducts();
  }
  deleteProducts(){
    this.deleteProduct();
  }
  
  addToCart(){
    console.log(this.productItem) //does not work. this.products returns the whole list of products
   // this.cartService.productToCart(this.productItem).subscribe(() => {
    //  this.msg.sendMsg(this.productItem)
  //  })
  }
 
  getProducts()
  {
    return this.http.get("products").subscribe(x => {
      this.products = x;
      console.log(this.products);
    });
  }
  deleteProduct()
  {

  //return this.http.delete(this.url).subscribe(data => {

    //console.log(data);
    return this.http.delete("products").subscribe(x => {
      this.products = x;
      console.log(this.products);
    });
  }
  //produstDelete(prod: Product){
    //console.log(prod)
   // let conf = confirm("sind Sie sicher ?");
    //if(conf)
    //  this.serviceproduct.produktDelete(prod);


  }
```

Btw just to say, my only part was the addToCart in this code. They dont comment anything out so I have no idea what they even do here...anyways, atm I just want to get ONE product.
When I do this.productItem, then the {} is completely empty. When i do this.products, i get the whole list of all the items.

This is the html part btw:

```
 <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor ="let product of products ">
                            <td> {{product.Name}}</td>
                            <td> {{product.Category}}</td>
                            <td> {{product.Price}}</td>
                            <td> <img src = "../assets/ProductPic/{{product.Pic}}"></td>
                            
                            <td><button class="btn-danger" (click)="deleteProduct()"> Löschen </button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn-change"  routerLink="/updateProduct/:id" routerLinkActive="active"> Change </button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn-cart" (click)="addToCart()"> In cart </button></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody>
```

I would really really appreciate if somebody could help, i add anything more that is needed and please no roast, I did watch Tutorials on it, but sometimes it do is hard to udnerstand things

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need the product available in the function, then edit the function signature in the componen:

```
addToCart(product: Product){
   this.productItem = product;
   console.log(this.productItem) //does not work. this.products returns the whole list of products
}
```

and include it in the HTML:

```
 <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor ="let product of products ">
         <td> {{product.Name}}</td>
         <td> {{product.Category}}</td>
         <td> {{product.Price}}</td>
         <td> <img src = "../assets/ProductPic/{{product.Pic}}"></td>
                        
         <td><button class="btn-danger" (click)="deleteProduct()"> Löschen </button></td>
         <td><button class="btn-change"  routerLink="/updateProduct/:id" routerLinkActive="active"> Change </button></td>
         <td><button class="btn-cart" (click)="addToCart(product)"> In cart </button></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```